# Difference between module scope and function scope

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, namespaces

While I have that structure into module scope:

```
def test():
    return 1


test = test()
print test
```

It works pretty fine.

But if I am trying same into function scope:

```
def test():
    return 1

def go():
    test = test()
    print test
```

I am getting `UnboundLocalError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my.py", line 16, in <module>
    go()
  File "my.py", line 12, in go
    test = test()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'test' referenced before assignment
```

I am a little bit confused. Why there is such difference between these behaviors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, `test` is defined in the same scope, so using `test` will reference to the function.

```
def test():
    return 1


test = test()
print test
```

while in this example, starting a line with `test=` will immediately erase the local reference to the function, and will mark it not assigned yet, so when you use `test()` it will tell you that the variable wasn't assigned.

```
def test():
    return 1

def go():
    # here
    test = test()
    print test
```

To get behaviour similar to the first example, you can add `nonlocal` or `global` where I marked `# here`, and I am pretty sure you will get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In second example, Python is trying to reference `test` before assignment. 
One needs to declare `test` as `nonlocal` or `global` depending on your requirements.

**Here is modified code:**

```
def test():
    return 1

def go():
    global test
    test = test()
    print test
```

**Output**

> > Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
> >         Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
> >
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >
> > > ```
> > > 1
> > > ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you defines 'test' as a local variable in 'go' function scope it creates new variable in functions namespace.So, when you called 'test()' inside the function it tried to access its local copy not the global function.The following code should work.

```
def test():
    return 1

def go():
    local_function_variable = test()
    print local_function_variable

go()
```