# Why does the below python code not throw error?

Tags: python, oop, scope

How does line 3 even get executed even though the function `two()` is defined below `one()` which makes it out of scope?!

```
def one():
    temp = "I am Aditya"
    return two
    
def two(temp):
        return "Hello "+temp

x = one
print(x()("Akshay"))
```

Output :
Hello Akshay

Comment: None of that code gets executed, since you're not calling either function. That's why there is no error.

Comment: If you call one() **after** the definition of two() you will not see any error(s) because *two* will be available from global scope. However, if you call one() in between the two definitions (i.e., before the definition of two()) you will get a NameError because two() doesn't yet exist

Comment: Did you want to write `return two(temp)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between module scope and function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265248/difference-between-module-scope-and-function-scope)

Comment: Sorry, I posted the incomplete question.
But I still don't understand how the output. How is the function two() getting returned even after It is out of scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

```
def one():
    temp = "I am Aditya"
    return two
```

Variables defined in the function `one()` are contained only inside the function scope.
When python reaches the line `return two`, you think that python will raise an error because `two` does not exist inside the function scope.

However, if variable not found, python will then go up 1 level into the global scope which the object `two` exist, which will then be fine.

If you try to call `one()` before defining `def two():` , you will get an error.

If you try to call `one()` after `def two():`  has been defined, no problem. To understand why, read below.

**Background explanation**

In python, everything is an object. A function is an "object", a variable `temp` is also an object of the str class, etc.

```
def two(temp):
        return "Hello "+temp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(two)
    print(two('sam'))
```

If you run the code, you will see this

```
<function two at 0x10ace2020>
Hello sam
[Finished in 51ms]
```

The object `two` is a function. Using `print()` on the object will show you the reference pointer to that object.

You have to use parenthesis `two()` to execute the function. Then, you will execute the code to return `Hello sam`

To answer your question, you need this deeper understanding into how python works. Hope you get it. Cheers :)

Comment: You've made things a lot more clear to me...thanks a lot !